# date format convert into varchar dd-mmm-yy format in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

today's date is ***2016-08-23*** in DATE format
and i want covert into a specific format like **1st Aug to 31st Aug, 2016** in VARCHAR format into sql.

> main purpose is i want first and last date of month in this specific format using with sql procedure or function.

so what should i do?

Comment: given there are a billion examples out there, the first thing you should do is try searching....

Comment: I am agree with @MitchWheat. Before post question search online. Try this : https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: see this for get first and last date in month http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-query-to-find-first-and-last-day-of-current-month/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query..

```
DECLARE @testdate DATETIME
SELECT @testdate = '2016-08-23'

SELECT LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@testdate)-1),@testdate),113),6)  
+' to '+LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@testdate))),
 DATEADD(mm,1,@testdate)),113),11) AS Date_Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 106) AS [DD MMM YYYY]
```

The third parameter can be changed due to the format you need.
for ex:

0 or 100 (1, 2) --  Default -- mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)

101 -- U.S. -- mm/dd/yyyy

102 -- ANSI -- yy.mm.dd

103 -- British/French -- dd/mm/yyyy

104 -- German -- dd.mm.yy

105 -- Italian -- dd-mm-yy

106 (1) -- - -- dd mon yy

107 (1) --  - -- Mon dd, yy

108 --  -  hh:mi:ss

9 or 109 (1, 2) -- Default + milliseconds -- mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)

110 -- USA -- mm-dd-yy

111 -- JAPAN -- yy/mm/dd

112 -- ISO -- yymmdd or yyyymmdd

13 or 113 (1, 2) -- Europe default + milliseconds -- dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)

114 --  - -- hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)

20 or 120 (2)  -- ODBC canonical -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)

21 or 121 (2) -- ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

126 (4) -- ISO8601 -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)

127(6, 7) -- ISO8601 with time zone Z. -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (no spaces)

130 (1, 2) -- Hijri (5) -- dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM

131 (2) -- Hijri (5) -- dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME   

SET @MyDate = '2016-08-23'  

SELECT  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@MyDate)-1),@MyDate),106)) 
--To Get The 1st Day OF Month  

Select Eomonth(@MyDate) -- TO Get The Last Date OF Month
```